# MapBox marker Cluster in Django

Tags: javascript, django, mapbox

help, please
I have used Django Mapbox for my project and after adding all the marker I was unable to use Marker Cluster like this plugin in the link
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markercluster-custom-polygon-appearance/

this is my code to export the marker on the map

```
                mapboxgl.accessToken = MKey;
                var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                    container: 'map',
                    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11?optimize=true',
                    center: [6.83, 42.12],
                    zoom: 4
                    });
                
                {% for r in resto %}
                    // dish of the day
                    var today = new Date();
                    var thisday = today.getDay();
                    var weekend = "{{ r.date_de_fin|date:'m-d-Y'}}";
                    var end = moment(new Date()).format("M-DD-y");
                    var week = weekend>=end;
                    console.log(thisday);
                    console.log(weekend);
                    console.log(end);
                    console.log(week);
                    if(week && thisday==0){
                        dish = '{{ r.dimanche }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_D }}';
                    }else if(week && thisday==1){
                        dish = '{{ r.lundi }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_L }}';
                    }else if(week && thisday==2){
                        dish = '{{ r.mardi }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_M }}';
                    }else if (week && thisday==3) {
                        dish = '{{ r.mercredi }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_ME}}';
                    }else if(week && thisday==4){
                        dish = '{{ r.jeudi }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_J}}'; 
                    }else if(week && thisday==5){
                        dish = '{{ r.vendredi }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_V}}';
                    }else if(week && thisday==6){
                        dish = '{{ r.samedi }}';
                        price = '{{ r.prix_de_plat_S}}';
                    }else{
                        dish = "Désolé, il n'y a pas de plat aujourd'hui";
                        price = "00"

                    };
                    
                    var LngLat =  {{ r.terrain|tuple_to_array }} ;
                        var geojson = {
                            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                            'features': [
                                {
                                    'type': 'Feature',
                                    'properties': {
                                        'iconSize': [48, 60]
                                    },
                                    'geometry': {
                                        'type': 'Point',
                                        'coordinates': LngLat
                                    }
                                },
                            ]
                            };
                            geojson.features.forEach(function (marker) {
                                var el = document.createElement('div');
                                el.className = 'marker';
                                el.style.backgroundImage =
                                'url({% static "img/marker/resto.png" %}';
                                el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
                                el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';
                                
                                new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                                .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                                .addTo(map).setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(
                                
                                    "<div class='col-md-12'>"+
                                        "<h5 style='color:#e21c12'><strong>{{ r.nom }}</strong></h5><p><strong>Tél: </stron><a href='tel:{{ r.tel|cut:' ' }}' style='text-decoration:none'>{{ r.tel }}</a></p>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<hr>"+
                                    "<div class='row'>" +
                                    "<div class='col-6'>"+
                                        "<h6>Plat du jour: </h6> "+
                                    "</div>" + 
                                    "<div class='col-6'>"+
                                        "<h3><span class='badge bg-success' style='background:#70ad47!important'>"+price+" €</span><h3/>"+
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "<div class='col-md-12'>"+
                                        "<p class='fw-normal'>"+dish+"</p>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<div class='d-grid gap-2'>"+
                                        "<a href='{{ r.get_absolute_url}}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='width:100%'>Découvrez tous nos plats</a>"+
                                    "</div>"
                                
                                ));
                            });
                {% endfor %}
                map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
                map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
                map.addControl(
                    new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
                        positionOptions: {
                            enableHighAccuracy: true
                        },
                        trackUserLocation: true
                        })
                );
```

so any one have any idea haw can I add MarkerCluster to my code

Comment: Are there any errors in console? Is the map rendering at least, just without the markers, or no map at all? Any chance you can set it up on jsfiddle to replicate then I can have a play to try and help

Comment: no error just i want to add cluster marker like they have in the link